# Could I be able to left-align the following equations? (Please note that one of which is mult-lined)

Tags: vertical-alignment, multline

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
    \begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
 &D=
\sum_{\epsilon(1,2,3)}\epsilon(1,2,3)a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}.&\\
&\end{flalign*}
\begin{multline*}
D=
\epsilon(1,2,3)a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}+\epsilon(1,3,2)a_{11}a_{23}a_{32}+
\epsilon(2,1,3)a_{12}a_{21}a_{33}+\\
\epsilon(2,3,1)a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}+\epsilon(3,1,2)a_{11}a_{21}a_{31}+
\epsilon(3,2,1)a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}.
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean line up the two "D =" ?

Comment: Yes, that was what I looked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mathtools` provides a `multlined` environment, which is to `multline` as `aligned` is to `align`, so you can use this within the `flalign`.
Note the negative space `\!`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe} % to indicate border of text area
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
 &D=
\sum_{\epsilon(1,2,3)}\epsilon(1,2,3)a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}.&\\
&\!\begin{multlined}
D=
\epsilon(1,2,3)a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}+\epsilon(1,3,2)a_{11}a_{23}a_{32}+
\epsilon(2,1,3)a_{12}a_{21}a_{33}+\\
\epsilon(2,3,1)a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}+\epsilon(3,1,2)a_{11}a_{21}a_{31}+
\epsilon(3,2,1)a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}.
\end{multlined}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much, Torbjørn. 
I shall be so grateful to you for providing me a coherent answer.

Comment: it's often more common to place the operator at the beginning of the continued line rather than at the end of the broken line.  (this *does* depend on the local typographic tradition; in traditional russian documents, it's placed in both locations.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, I can never remember which is more common.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just change the margin size of math environments by putting the following in your preamble:

```
%%  -> Define horizontal spacing for equations
\setlength{\mathindent}{length}
```

where you could change `length` to any length you prefer.  For instance, if you use `1cm`, it will shift the equation towards the left-hand side of the page significantly from its default position.  You can also use the range type of input (e.g., `0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt`) for `length` if you desire.  Note that `length` can be negative as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `split` within the `flalign`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
D={} & \sum_{\epsilon(1,2,3)}\epsilon(1,2,3)a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}\\
\begin{split}
D={} & \epsilon(1,2,3)a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}+\epsilon(1,3,2)a_{11}a_{23}a_{32}+
\epsilon(2,1,3)a_{12}a_{21}a_{33}+\\
   & \epsilon(2,3,1)a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}+\epsilon(3,1,2)a_{11}a_{21}a_{31}+
\epsilon(3,2,1)a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}
\end{split}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't left align them though.

Comment: To Greyshade, 
Since I just started working with LaTex, I was not aware of Split-environment. I could use this method for my work as well. 
Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Same code. Slightly modified with `align*` environment

code

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
    \begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 D &=\sum_{\epsilon(1,2,3)}\epsilon(1,2,3)a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}.\\
 D &=\epsilon(1,2,3)a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}\\
   &= +\epsilon(1,3,2)a_{11}a_{23}a_{32}\\
   &= +\epsilon(2,1,3)a_{12}a_{21}a_{33}\\
   &= +\epsilon(2,3,1)a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}\\
    &=+\epsilon(3,1,2)a_{11}a_{21}a_{31}\\
    &=+\epsilon(3,2,1)a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}.\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: multialign]

Comment: Sure you want all those equals signs?